# SQL View for calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql, view, calculated-columns

I have a table named games with these columns: `home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score`

I want to create a view that adds a column `winner` which sets the winner to the `home_team`, `away_team` or `'TIE'` (if the scores are equal).

Can this be done using a view?  I need the winner to be calculated on the fly and not stored in a table. I also do not want to use a trigger.

I'm using MySQL 5.5 as my SQL server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Psuedo-code not having your schema available...

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN home_score > away_score THEN home_team
         WHEN home_score < away_score THEN away_team
         ELSE 'TIE'
       END CASE
```

This assumes that your `home_team` and `away_team` columns are some sort of `varchar` type.

Also this isn't checking for `NULL`, so if scores can be `NULL` you'll need to handle that in the `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: This worked perfectly, except I did not need the END CASE, just END